# UWP Graphic glitch when selecting a MenuItem of a NavigationView generated in code behind

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a NavigationView and some NavigationViewItems generated in code behind.
From the code I was trying to select one NavigationViewItem that was the default one showed to the user at launch and I expirienced a strange behavior
(this behavior doesn't happen if you select a NavigationViewItem that was generated in the xaml).

When I launch the app I can't see the selection (the accent colored rectangle on the left of the NavigationViewItem) but when I click another NavigationViewItem the rectangle shows up and start the animation that moves it from the old NavigationViewItem to the new one.

I followed the same code that I found on the documentation with the exception that in the documentation they select a NavigationViewItem that was generated in the xaml.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview

[image: image to show better the problem]

Here is the code to reproduce the problem (minimum version and target version of the project: Win10 FCU Build 16299)

XAML:

```
<NavigationView x:Name="navView" Loaded="navView_Loaded">

</NavigationView>

<Button Content="Select Mail" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

c#:

```
private void navView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    navView.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem()
    { Content = "Home", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Home), Tag = "home" });

    navView.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem()
    { Content = "My content", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Folder), Tag = "content" });

    navView.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem()
    { Content = "Mail", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Mail), Tag = "mail" });

    foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in navView.MenuItems)
    {
        if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "home")
        {
            navView.SelectedItem = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    navView.SelectedItem = navView.MenuItems.ElementAt(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have do more things in the `navView_Loaded` cause `SelectionIndicator` animation terminate. You could add `await Task.Delay(500);` before setting `NavigationView` selectedItem to verify this.

```
await  Task.Delay(500);
foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in navView.MenuItems)
{
    if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "home")
    {

        navView.SelectedItem = item;
        (navView.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem).IsSelected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

For your scenario, you could add the `MenuItems` in the `Loading` event handler method and set the select item in the Loaded event handler method.

```
private void navView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in navView.MenuItems)
    {
        if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "home")
        {

            navView.SelectedItem = item;
            (navView.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem).IsSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
private void navView_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
{
    navView.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem()
    { Content = "Home", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Home), Tag = "home" });

    navView.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem()
    { Content = "My content", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Folder), Tag = "content" });

    navView.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem()
    { Content = "Mail", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Mail), Tag = "mail" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me more why your code works? Using what I posted and adding `<NavigationView.MenuItems> <NavigationViewItem Content="Hello" Tag="hello"/> </NavigationView.MenuItems>` into the XAML and changing the .cs with `&& item.Tag.ToString() == "hello"` works normally! Why selecting and item generated in code make the issue happen?

And also, what is this for? `(navView.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem).IsSelected = true;`

The item shows the indicator even using just this line: `navView.SelectedItem = item;`.